# Can a service account push changes to Azure Repos?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-devops, azure-repos

With a CMS system where the content is stored in JSON files we want to use a repo to track and approve changes. When an editor makes a change we would like the server to be able to commit and push the changes to the repo, and then create a pull request. We want to be able to do this with a service account, not the editor's account.

I thought I'd be able to create an Azure AAD app registration so I could create an oauth2 bearer token to use with my api request, but I don't see how to give that account access to the repo. The portal has an API permissions item where I can give my app permissions to Azure DevOps, but it is only user impersonation/delagated permissions, the option to provide permissions to the application itself is disabled.

Is it possible to do what we are trying to do?

UPDATED: Things I've tried

1) I created an AAD App and created a secret for that app so I could use the appId and secret to get a bearer token. I then tried to add API permissions to DevOps for my app but it only allows me to create delegated permissions as application permissions is disabled. I feel if I could give the neccesary permissions to this app I'd have the problem solved.

2) I've attempted to find a way in DevOps and Repos to allow my AAD app access, but the app does not appear anywhere I've looked. All I see is users and groups and my app does not appear in either of those lists.

3) I've registered an app at https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/app/register and have an appId and secret. I'm skeptical about this because it required a callback url and I'm trying to use client_credentials. When I attept to obtain a token with this appId and secret and calling https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token, the service returns a 400 error. My POST to request a bearer token included the payload client_id={the clientId}&client_secret={the secret}&grant_type=client_credentials and a content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded. The same code succeeds when I set the url to https://login.microsoftonline.com and use the AAD appId and secret, but that identity does not have access to DevOps for reasons discussed above.

4) I've reviewed the samples at https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples but most of those are interactive and won't meet the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you donot want to use the editor's account.  You can just create a Personal Access Token, and select the **full Code** scope for this token. Then you can use this Person access token to make api request to azure devops server. You can check the detailed steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to create Person access token.

[image]

Below is a powershell script example to call azure devops api. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#assemble-the-request) it is in C# using the HttpClient class.

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/...."

$connectionToken="Personal Access Token"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method get
```

You can also try creating a dummy user to add it in your organization, Thus you can use this dummy user account to perform above actions.

If you want to [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops). You have to follow the authorization flow use callback url to get the authorization code.

[client_credentials authorization flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) is for azure and not available for azure devops.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a PAT because I thought it had to be tied to a user account. After some discussion we feel we should be able to create a service account which can be used to generate a PAT. We're working that angle now. Thanks.

Comment: @TimHeikell Any updates on your approach with using a service account for pushing changes to the Git repository? We are also discussing possible solutions to handle machine-to-machine communication with Azure DevOps without being tied to a "real" user!